# Cannot run installation on Windows Vista

Tags: configuration, tor-install

Just finished downloading the installation file for the browser and when I click on the file it does not open.   What is wrong ?

Comment: Have you verified it's checksum? Is it for a correct platform, i.e. 32-bit for 32-bit OS ?

Answer (score 2):

You may have to run the installation program as Administrator. Right click on the program icon and choose "Run as Administrator". Works on Vista if you are running a 32 bit program via the 64 bit platform.